# Is there a way to return the result of field_value_factor for every document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query where I apply a boost using the field_value_factor:

```
{
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "field_value_factor":{
            "field":"books.total_count",
            "modifier":"log1p",
            "missing":0
         },
         "query":{
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would like that the query return the value of the boost calculated by the field_value_factor for every document.

I could use the "explain" to get this value, but in my tests it seems to slow down the response, and I need it for every query.

I could also calculate the boost value in the code (outside of elasticsearch), but I prefer not to go with this approach.

Do you know any other way I could get this value from the query?

Comment: I think so that not possible.